# Why is a struct of two doubles passed via registers but a struct of three doubles passed on the stack?

Tags: c, struct, calling-convention, cdecl

The following code:

```c
struct Double2 {
    double a;
    double b;
};

struct Double3 {
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
};

double double2(struct Double2 x) {
    return x.a + x.b;
}

double double3(struct Double3 x) {
    return x.a + x.b + x.c;
}

double double_args(double a, double b, double c) {
    return a + b + c;
}
```

compiles to

```
double2:
        addsd   xmm0, xmm1
        ret
double3:
        movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsp+8]
        addsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsp+16]
        addsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsp+24]
        ret
double_args:
        addsd   xmm0, xmm1
        addsd   xmm0, xmm2
        ret
```

on Linux, x86-64 with GCC 9.2 with -O3 ([Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/dmIE1D))

Why is a struct of two doubles (`Double2`) passed via the registers `xmm0` and `xmm1`, but a struct of three doubles (`Double3`) is passed via the stack? `double_args()` demonstrates that the compiler is at least capable of passing three doubles via registers.

Is this specified as part of the C calling convention? What is the relevant rule?

Comment: You need to find the [application binary interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) (ABI) for the implementation that you are using.

Comment: Calling conventions are implementation-dependent, the C specification says nothing about this.

Comment: That is the decision of the compiler developer. Apparently, there aren't enough registers for a struct of three doubles.

Comment: Really no relevant rule unfortunately. GCC guys chose to do it this way.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie well, there are enough registers, GCC devs just didn't care about it.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli As I understand it, GCC doesn't have complete freedom with how it implements this, since the functions have external linkage and could be called from code compiled with a different compiler or even from a different language via FFI. I think it would be specified somewhere.

Comment: @user3386109 I think you are right. It may be specified in this file somewhere: https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/402129/mpx-linux64-abi.pdf

Comment: Per [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions), GCC uses several different ABIs, so which it uses may depend on how it was configure, what the target system is, and what switches are specified. Each ABI specifies how arguments are passed, based on characteristics such as type of argument (e.g., integer or floating-point), size, alignment requirements, and position in the argument list. Quite likely the ABI in use specifies general arguments up to 16 bytes are passed in registers if available, and larger arguments are passed on the stack.

Comment: For example, looking at the [System V ABI [draft version]](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/402129/mpx-linux64-abi.pdf), a three-double struct has three members of class SSE (page 19), and then, because the structure exceeds “two eightbytes” and the latter two are not in class SSEUP, the whole argument is passed in memory (item 5 on page 21). But I have not read/used/interpreted this ABI in a while, so I could be off.

Comment: @Jesse well... you're most probably right, after all as you said compatibility with existing compiled programs needs to be maintained, and you need to adhere a specific ABI for that. Still don't know if GCC follows a specific ABI or more.

Comment: IIRC, there is a similar threshold possible for the return value, in case it is of struct type, in GCC backends. If it is small, it may be returned in registers.